# Select links with certain attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, href

i am trying to select all links with a certain attribute, for some reason it dosent work, can anyone help ?

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Edit">Edit</a>
```

JQUERY

```
$('a[title="Edit"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attribute selector looks correct. I suspect you are failing to attach that click handler when the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for JavaScript processing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[title="Edit"]').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault;
        alert($(this).attr('title'));
    });
});
```

Comment: How the hell did i missed that XD